# input type time - If the time is entered, make it mandatory to enter the minutes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, time

I would like to make the input of minutes mandatory when the time is filled in to avoid this situation:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbibH.png)
How can we solve the problem ? in Js Jquery ?
Thanks for your help!

Here is my line in HTML

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="TEST" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that if you use the input type: time, it's mandatory to enter the minutes.

Here's a resource that might help you:
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Comment: Supplying an example can help improve this answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I added a resource from Mozilla to help TheoB with their question